# set G equal to what?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

My attempts :  i construct a matrix  $A= \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&2&1&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&2&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&2&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&2&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&2&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$

Now  we know that the characteristic polynomial of A is $(x − 1)^2
(x − 2)^6$
and the minimal polynomial of A is$ (x − 1)(x − 2)^2$

Now we will  take  only eigenvalue $ 2$  of $ A$  that  is  characteristic  of eigenvalue $2  =(x-2)^6$ and the minimial of eigenvalue $2 = (x-1)^2$

Now  set  G will   be    equal to  $ 6- 2 = 4$

so  $G = 4$

Is  my answer is correct or nots?  pliz reply

i  have  my exam tommorrows. so  i need its  urgently   any Hints/solution

Thanks in advance   i would be more thankful

Comment: Since $G$ is a set of possible $k$ values, it wouldn't equal $4$, but it might equal $\{4\}$, in which case the cardinality of $G$ would be $1$. Do you want the set itself, or its cardinality?

Comment: @G Tony  i mean to say  about  set  G that  what is   possible k value ?

Comment: i have edit my question again about set G...

Comment: @stupid I think set $G$ should be $\{1,4\}$.

Comment: @gimusi can  u little more  elaborate  its ??

Comment: @stupid do not accept until the answer is not confirmed also by other users! Bye

Comment: okks,,, @gimusi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the matrix $A$ we have an eigenvalue $2$ which has geometric multiplicity $4$ and one which has geometric multiplicity $1$ (the one of the jordan block $2-by-2$). Thus we have that $G=\{1,4\}$.

Comment: The possible jordan forms for $A\in\mathcal{A}$ are  $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&2&1&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&2&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&2&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&2&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&2&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&2&1&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&2&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&2&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&2&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&2&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&2&1&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&2&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&2&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&2&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&2&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}.$$

So $G=\{1,2,4\}$.